# Как "найти и заменить по ВПР" по списку, часть текста

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть в [Гугл таблицах](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUKtYpDF8mynTKfItpC5tbcLkIrsu3eYEeY4ATxVVB0/edit?usp=sharing):

1. Список файлов для переименования
2. Список старых названий
3. и параллельно ему список новых названий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо заменить старые названия на новые, сохранив при этом формат фалов suffix prefix.

Думаю надо найти "Старое название" в "Списке файлов" и заменить на "Новое название" по ВПР

Что пребывал:

1. Удалить формат suffix prefix , потом по ВПР подобрать замену, но потом не понятно как вернуть такой же формат suffix prefix

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(C2:C;".JPG";"");".PDF";"");".AI";"");".SLDDRW";"");".SLDPRT";"");".jpg";"");".png";""))
```

2.Разделить по точке "." не получится так как в названии есть точки, да и проблемы с suffix/prefix

[Пример таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUKtYpDF8mynTKfItpC5tbcLkIrsu3eYEeY4ATxVVB0/edit?usp=sharing)

Уточнение 1: в некоторых названиях может быть несколько "." и "_"

Уточнение 2: строк примерно 800

Comment: Можно цепляться за скобку и нижнее подчеркивание, но выбивается из общего строя *Старое-название-1.SLDDRW*. Если возможен такой же вариант, но с двумя точками, то решение формулами будет сложным

Answer (score 0):

Из-за названия, в котором нет нижнего подчеркивания, приходится обходить ошибку и рисовать формулу в два раза длиннее:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(                                  
ВПР(ЛЕВБ(A3;ПОИСК("_";A3)-1);$B$3:$C$20;2;0)&ПСТР(A3;ПОИСК("_";A3);99);                                 
ВПР(ЛЕВБ(A3;ПОИСК(".";A3)-1);$B$3:$C$20;2;0)&ПСТР(A3;ПОИСК(".";A3);99))
```

Comment: Есть уточнение: в названии может быть несколько "." и "_", и в этих случаях ваша формула не работает, поэтому я и отказался от привязки к ним.

Comment: Об этом я и писал в комментарии к вопросу. Для упрощения вычислений нужно задействовать несколько столбцов. Или решать задачу  скриптами js

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что нужно заменить не "часть теста", а левую часть имени файла. Тогда справедливо:

**для замены всех, ненайденные переименовываются сами в себя**:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
  ROW(A2:A25);
  SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
    REGEXMATCH(A2:A25;TRANSPOSE(B2:B25));
    ROW(A2:A25) & "❤" & REGEXREPLACE(A2:A25;TRANSPOSE(B2:B25);TRANSPOSE(C2:C25));
  ));"❤");
  2;
);A2:A25))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**для замены всех, ненайденные возвращают пустоту**:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
  ROW(A2:A25);
  SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
    REGEXMATCH(A2:A25;TRANSPOSE(B2:B25));
    ROW(A2:A25) & "❤" & REGEXREPLACE(A2:A25;TRANSPOSE(B2:B25);TRANSPOSE(C2:C25));
  ));"❤");
  2;
);))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следует обратить внимание, что сортировка диапазона **B2:C25** может повлиять на результат работы формулы.

Для более сложной ***однопартийной*** замены нужно усложнять формулу `REGEXREPLACE(A2:A25;TRANSPOSE(B2:B25);TRANSPOSE(C2:C25))`

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfF88hVRfMumLDPXdUU-R4dr3oDycDrBlSoCFLgy148/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Работает, но на практике, когда много строк (800) зависает. Можно ли облегчить расчёт?

Comment: Не знаю. Вроде, для небольшого списка замен (до 100 пар) не должно вообще зависать. Думаю, что лучше воспользоваться скриптами.

Comment: Итого: я использовал другую вашу формулу, тока перед этим пробелы заменил на "_", сработало хорошо, и без зависаний.
=ИНДЕКС(IFS(
  REGEXMATCH(A3:A;"_\(.+\)\..*$");
  REGEXREPLACE(A3:A;REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)_\(.+\)\..*$");ВПР(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)_\(.+\)\..*$");B3:C32;2;));
  REGEXMATCH(A3:A;"\(.+\)\..*$");
  REGEXREPLACE(A3:A;REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)\(.+\)\..*$");ВПР(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)\(.+\)\..*$");B3:C32;2;));
  REGEXMATCH(A3:A;"\..*$");
  REGEXREPLACE(A3:A;REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)\..*$");ВПР(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A;"(.+)\..*$");B3:C32;2;))
))

Comment: К сожалению, не могу проверить. На тех данных, которые у меня есть, формула не работает. Но идея про пробелы интересная для оценки нагрузки на расчеты формул вообще. Мне эта формула показалась сложной, поэтому не стал дорабатывать.